# Abnormal ec2 usage

Tags: amazon-ec2

I found that my ec2 has abnormal usage diagram after 15th May 2017. The credit balance drops from 150 to 0, the credit usage surge up from 0 to 5. The ec2 instance was used to host a wordpress previously.

Is the server been compromised?

The link of the diagram as follows.

[image]

Comment: Or someone finally visited your blog.

Comment: I dont think so, if it is, i think also is been attacked. because it is so much till the website went down.